# Multiplying Sigmas(sums)

Tags: summation, products

I would be grateful if someone please rewrite or expand this please.
I have problem multiplying two sigmas ($\sum $)

$$
(d(n)-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k)) \times (d(n)-\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} h_l x(n-l))^{*}
$$

By the way $^*$ is the conjugate.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
& \left(d(n)-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k)\right) \times \left(d(n)-\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} h_l x(n-l)\right)^{*} \tag{1}\\
& = \left(d(n)-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k)\right) \times \left(d(n)^* -\left(\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} h_l x(n-l)\right)^*\right) \tag{2}\\
& = d(n)d(n)^* - d(n)^*\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k) - d(n) \left(\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} h_l x(n-l)\right)^* + \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k) \right)\left(\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} h_l x(n-l)\right)^* \tag{3}\\
& = d(n)d(n)^* - d(n)^*\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k) - d(n) \left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k)\right)^* + \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k) \right)\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k)\right)^* \tag{4}\\
& = |d(n)|^2 - 2\,\mathbb{R}\left\{d(n)^*\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k)\right\} + \left| \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} h_k x(n-k) \right|^2\tag{5}\\
\end{align}$$

where $\mathbb{R}$ is the real part of a complex number.

From $(1)$ to $(2)$ we use the fact that $(a \pm b)^*$ = $a^* \pm b^*$.

From $(2)$ to $(3)$ we use the fact that $(a + b)(c + d)$ = $ac + ad + bc + bd$.

From $(3)$ to $(4)$ we use the fact that $\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} f(l) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f(k)$ (and that is how the $l$ disappears, it has no meaning outside of the sum).

From $(4)$ to $(5)$ we use the fact that $a \times a^* = |a|^2$ and $a^*b + ab^* = 2\mathbb{R}\left\{a^*b\right\} = 2\mathbb{R}\left\{ab^*\right\}$.

Comment: Thank u very much for helping me, I really appreciate it, especially that I got totally disappointed to receive an answer. I learned couple of points, but I think you're missing some points. such as subscript $l$ is totally disappeared in your result! Furthermore, I don't think if $(x(n-l))^*$ expands to $x^*(n^*-l^*)$ would be correct, at least not to my knowledge of math :( which is quite poor!
Would you please tell me why $\mathbb{R}$ appeared? I don't get it.
Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: You are correct about me going to far with the conjugate, I'll fix that now.  As far as the $l$ disappearing, that is fine: $$\sum_{l=-\infty}^{\infty} f(l) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f(k)$$ you can chose whatever for the variable.

Comment: About your question, first of all you have to give people time to respond.  If you act entitled (as if people are obligated to respond) you will likely get people who won't help you even if they can.\\  Second, if you post your question and give the impression that you have no intention of learning the background and only want the result, some people (especially those who never left university) will be offended.  I don't personally mind; I think it is a virtue of mathematics to only need results, but here it helps to at least pretend to care.  Just don't forget that no one is obliged to help.

Comment: Daniel Thanks so much for your comments, and answers.

I love to learn these damn things, believe me I love them although I don't understand them clearly. I'm even thinking of pursuing a degree in Math.

This is problem is related to either Wiener Filter or Least Mean Square (LMS) algorithm, I've already implemented the filter in MATLAB, but I still wanna know about every bit of its mechanism which is pure math. Unfortunately $l$ can't be replaced by $k$, as I clearly remember that $l$ was carried through the rest of formulas.

I'll try to find the document and attach it here

Tnx a million$

Comment: Thanks so much for your step by step explanation.

I didn't know about 

$$a^*b + ab^* = 2\mathbb{R}\left\{a^*b\right\} = 2\mathbb{R}\left\{ab^*\right\}$$

I'm trying to work it out! Nice!!!!!! :)

Comment: I didn't know it either.  But it looks like it should be simplified, so I wrote $a = w + i\,x$, $b = y + i\,z$, and worked from there.  Development is one of the best ways to learn math, but given the interests you have displayed, I would suggest a degree in electrical, hardware, or software engineering and at most minor in math.  Obviously do what you want, but realize that the style of math you learn as a math major and the style of math you learn as a developer are very different.

Comment: Dear Daniel

give me couple of days, to find the document regarding my question.I have a degree in Electrical eng, Wireless Communication & finally, Electron beam probing, involves signal processing. I believe the most I'm missing now is sophisticated Math & statistics. The problem with MATLAB, which I love it, is that it simplifies everything, even an illiterate person can use fft.

But I've this curiosity disease to understand what am I doing, although the LMS problem is solved, but I'm not satisfied yet :(
Thanks to ppl like you, internet and etc, I'm learning but the pace isn't satisfying.